# PhoneGap build webkit-appearance no drop down arrow for select tag

Tags: cordova, select, drop-down-menu, phonegap

I'm using PhoneGap build and my select tags have no dropdown arrow on the phone.
I tried applying `-webkit-appearance: menulist;` but this doesn't help, I tried other choices but still just shows the option with no drop down arrow.

It an issue with PhoneGap because the same code shows a dropdown arrow on the native browser on my Android phone.

Only once I use PhoneGap build does the arrow disappear. Any solutions?

Comment: Using the phonegap-start app and adding a `<select>` tag i was still able to view the dropdown arrow as well as the native select menu (using phonegap build). I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: I used phonegap build 2.2 and android 4.2.1. The select box acts as if it has -webkit-appearance: none; applied but I never apply it and I can't override it

Answer (score 4):

The Android Browser's rendering of `<select>`s is buggy and will remove the normal styling if a background or border is applied.

Since `<select>`s not looking like `<select>`s is a pretty big usability issue, your best bet is to not style them for this browser only.

Unfortunately, there's no pure CSS way of selecting/excluding the Android Browser, so I recommend you use Layout Engine (https://github.com/stowball/Layout-Engine), which will add a class of `.browser-android` to the `<html>` tag.

You could then style all `<select>`s except on Android Browser, like so:

```
html:not(.browser-android) select {
    background: #0f0;
    border: 1px solid #ff0;
}
```