# Bootstrap Select not appearing correctly in Chrome

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, razor

I have a form in a ASP.NET MVC project using bootstrap that makes use of several select elements using the Razor helper:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.project_type, project_type_items, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Which creates the element:

```
<select id="project_type" class="form-control">
```

This works just fine in IE and Firefox but viewed in Chrome, the arrow on the drop down list is missing so that the element appears to be a text input. Clicking on the element will still display the select menu however.

In researching this I did not find info regarding this issue in Chrome, however I did stumble across a similar issue regarding the default Android browser:
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/
and [PhoneGap build webkit-appearance no drop down arrow for select tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14738203/phonegap-build-webkit-appearance-no-drop-down-arrow-for-select-tag)

My question is: why are these selects not rendering correctly in Chrome and is there a work around for this?

Thanks!

Comment: May or may not be related but you're missing the closing `"` for your `form-control` class.

Comment: @NicolásCarlo oops, I'll edit that. It's correct in my code, I simplified it here instead of copy/paste. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found a solution without requiring a workaround. This was perhaps silly; I am using a bootstrap theme from bootswatch in which the css for select had `-webkit-appearance: none`

The following edit solved the issue in Chrome (and presumably Safari):

```
select.form-control {
    -webkit-appearance: menulist;
}
```

as per [W3](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_appearance.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap class `.form-control` works fine in Chrome with the following example:

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
    <option value="four">Four</option>
    <option value="five">Five</option>
</select>
```

However, if you're looking for a workaround because it just isn't working for you then you can do something like this:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Trash", new {post.Id})" class="btn btn-danger" data-post="Are you sure you want to trash this post?"> Trash</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", new {post.Id})"> Delete</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The above is a work around I got from a tutorial that I use more than the regular class provided by Bootstrap.